# Float action button anchor with include layout

Tags: android, material-design

do you know if it is possible to use the id views included in a layout as anchor of a FAB ? For example :

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/map"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
```

**"@id/map" is inside the inclued layout *content_main*.**

With this code I currently get the follow error:

> Error:(30, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_anchor' with value '@id/map').

For information I'm use the *include* for trying to reduce my main layout size.

It seem that "@id/map" is not visible for the FAB anchor. But I perhaps doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are missing **Tag Id** `android:id="@+id/map"`

Open your `@layout/content_main`

> Floating action buttons are used for a special type of promoted
>   action. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating above the UI
>   and have special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and
>   the transferring anchor point.

```
Error:(30, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_anchor' with value '@id/map').
```

Comment: I apologize for the late answer. You are right Amiya, it was a typo in the include file. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If that can help, I had the same problem again. Because I use `app:layout_anchor="@id/textView"` instead of `app:layout_anchor="@+id/textView"`. I think we cannot use `"@id/..."` with an included id.

Answer (score 0):

I think plus"+" is missing in app:layout_anchor="@+id/map"

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it's because the AppBarLayout is declared after the view calling it as anchor in the xml file.